# How to automatically list related pages on Wiki-Pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, sharepoint-library, sitepages

A SharePoint page should be among other things used by our developers to store developer documentation. I don't really know much about SharePoint sites yet, but I thought that wiki sites are the best way to do that. 
So I created a Sitepage library on my Sharepoint website.
The developer should create in this there Wiki Pages. Related pages should be listed automatic on the page.

How can I implement the (automatic) listing of related pages on wiki-pages - I have no ideas...

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you can list related pages on one wiki page, at least not via OOB solutions.

A few things need to be taken into consideration:

1. How are these pages related? Are you considering displaying page URLs?
2. What so you mean “developer documentation”? If you are referring to documents, document libraries would be more appropriate.
3. Related documents are supported in document library with another list web part using classic experience. Also you can use lookup column to make connections to other documents.

Here are some posts with similar requests for your references:

[Self Referencing Related Documents Library Through Lookup Column.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68641/self-referencing-related-documents-library-through-lookup-column)

[Display related documents.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/884b4101-8da4-4879-9d49-1db9dc0310c8/display-related-documents?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: Hello, I would like to answer your questions below, maybe you can help me with my new Information. (1.) The page has a custom column with a tag. (2.) I dont want to refrerring to documents, I would like to refrerring to wiki-pages. (3.) I want to use wiki pages.

Comment: Chelsea_MSFT, I have clicked the links and read it. But I dont find anything what helps me...